# "Looping" listview in fragment with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

what i trying to do is, swipe page, differrent content in each page,

looping the Listview each page with provided data, but i getting force close while run, i'm new to android i don't know how to debug...

in php i can use `exit(var_dump($var));` and javascript `console.log(var);`
but in android, how do i debug?

the logcat error information is so many rows and like no details?

and why am i getting force close?

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.vronn.tabs;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabPagerAdapter tabPagerAdapter;
    public static String[] tabs = { "tab a", "tab b", "tab c" };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        tabPagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            /**
             * on swipe select the respective tab
             * */
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

}
```

> TabPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.vronn.tabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("tab",index);
        SwipeTabFragment swipeTabFragment = new SwipeTabFragment();
        swipeTabFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return swipeTabFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MainActivity.tabs.length;
    }
}
```

> SwipeTabFragment.java(old)

```
package com.vronn.tabs;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SwipeTabFragment extends Fragment {

    private int tab;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_tab, null);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        tab = bundle.getInt("tab");

        ArrayList<ContentContainer> myContent = getTabArr(tab);

        // Logcat show error on the following line, Tag: AndroidRunTime
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(container.getContext(), myContent);
        // MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), myContent);

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);




//        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
//        tv.setText(tab);
        return view;
    }

    private ArrayList<ContentContainer> getTabArr(int tab) {
        ArrayList<ContentContainer> myContent = new ArrayList<ContentContainer>();

         switch(tab) {
            case 0:
                myContent = getTabDefaultArr();
            break;
            case 1:
                myContent = getTabOneArr();
            break;
            case 2:
                myContent = getTabTwoArr();
            break;
         }

         return myContent;
    }

    private ArrayList<ContentContainer> getTabDefaultArr() {
        ArrayList<ContentContainer> myContent = new ArrayList<ContentContainer>();

        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content1"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content2"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content3"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content4"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content5"));

        return myContent;
    }

    private ArrayList<ContentContainer> getTabOneArr() {
        ArrayList<ContentContainer> myContent = new ArrayList<ContentContainer>();

        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content1"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content2"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content3"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content4"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content5"));

        return myContent;
    }

    private ArrayList<ContentContainer> getTabTwoArr() {
        ArrayList<ContentContainer> myContent = new ArrayList<ContentContainer>();

        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content1"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content2"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content3"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content4"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content5"));

        return myContent;
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<ContentContainer> myContent;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyListAdapter(Context swipeTabFragment, ArrayList<ContentContainer> results) {
            myContent = results;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(swipeTabFragment);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null) {
                itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            ContentContainer currentContent = myContent.get(position);

            // Get the icon
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
//          imageView.setImageResource(currentContent.getIcon());
//          ImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(currentContent.getIcon());

            // Year
            TextView itemName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            itemName.setText(currentContent.getName());

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myContent.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return myContent.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

> ContentContainer.java

```
package com.vronn.tabs;

public class ContentContainer {
    private String icon;
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private String content;

    public ContentContainer(String icon, String name, int year, String content) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

> list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_item">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="80dp"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/one" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/item_year"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

im unable to run this app because its error, is this working or totally wrong way?

updated, i made `SwipeTabFragment.java` to be like the following, but still force close, really no idea why, can someone help me out

```
package com.vronn.tabs;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SwipeTabFragment extends Fragment {

    private int tab;
    private ArrayList<ContentContainer> myContent = new ArrayList<ContentContainer>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_tab, null);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        tab = bundle.getInt("tab");

        getTabArr(tab);
        ArrayAdapter<ContentContainer> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);




//        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
//        tv.setText(tab);
        return view;
    }

    private void getTabArr(int tab) {
         switch(tab) {
            case 0:
                getTabDefaultArr();
            break;
            case 1:
                getTabOneArr();
            break;
            case 2:
                getTabTwoArr();
            break;
         }
    }

    private void getTabDefaultArr() {
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content1"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content2"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content3"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content4"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("one", "w", 1989, "hehehe this is content5"));
    }

    private void getTabOneArr() {
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content1"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content2"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content3"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content4"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("two", "s", 1994, "hehehe this is content5"));
    }

    private void getTabTwoArr() {
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content1"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content2"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content3"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content4"));
        myContent.add(new ContentContainer("three", "b", 1989, "hehehe this is content5"));
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContentContainer> {

        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null) {
                Log.e("msg", "empty itemView");
            }

            ContentContainer currentContent = myContent.get(position);

            // Get the icon
//          ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
//          imageView.setImageResource(currentContent.getIcon());
//          ImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(currentContent.getIcon());

            // Year
            TextView itemName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            itemName.setText(currentContent.getName());

            return itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fix it, because i don't have an ListView created in the pager xml,

> SwipeTabFragment.java

this line

```
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
```

should be

```
//swipe_tab.xml should add a ListView with id listView1
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

> swipe_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cecece">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) it's about how to use log
you can add a specific message to logcat for example:

```
Log.e("Msg","your message goes here");
```